# How to download Magnolia cms community edition?

Tags: java, download, content-management-system, magnolia

I want to test Magnolia cms (open source edition). But I can't download it.

I'm trying to download it from:

http://www.magnolia-cms.com/product/try/download/ce-registration.html

but when I fill out my info I get the following:

There was 1 error:
Error 7726

Can I download it from somewhere else or how can I download it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry you couldn't download Magnolia from our site. There seems to have been a small issue with with this form, which has now been corrected.

If you have any trouble in future, you can always download the source files directly from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/magnolia/files

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 1):

You can use the maven archetypes from here

> mvn archetype:generate
>   -DarchetypeCatalog=https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/groups/public/

Create a simple empty webapp selecting the option 5, and you can add simple modules in the project selecting option 1.

You will find some useful tips [here](http://dev.magnolia-cms.com/~gjoseph/dont-build-magnolia-build-your-projects)

Answer (score 1):

If you want you can download a bundle with tomcat from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magnolia/files/)